# List append not working Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a script to remove bad characters from a csv file then to be stored in a list.

The script runs find but doesn't remove bad characters so I'm a bit puzzled any pointers or help on why it's not working is appreciated

```
def remove_bad(item):
    item = item.replace("%", "")
    item = item.replace("test", "")
    return item


raw = [] 

with open("test.csv", "rb") as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rows:
        raw.append((remove_bad(row[0].strip()),
                    row[1].strip().title()))

print raw
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of a few rows of your csv and an example of your expected output, and also say explicitly which bad chars you'd like to remove. With the information you provide, it is a bit difficult to help.

Comment: In spite of the question's title, the problem isn't that append isn't working, but that the code isn't removing all the bad characters. As @Adrianus' answer says, call remove_bad for both items in the input.

Answer (score 2):

If I have a csv-file with one line:

```
tst%,testT
```

Then your script, slightly modified, should indeed filter the "bad" characters. I changed it to pass both items separately to `remove_bad` (because you mentioned you had to "remove bad characters from a csv", not only the first row):

```
import csv

def remove_bad(item):
    item = item.replace("%","")
    item = item.replace("test","")
    return item


raw = [] 

with open("test.csv", "rb") as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rows:
        raw.append((remove_bad(row[0].strip()), remove_bad(row[1].strip()).title()))

print raw
```

Also, I put `title()` after the function call (else, `"test"` wouldn't get filtered out).

Output (the rows will get stored in a list as tuples, as in your example):

```
[('tst', 'T')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to ask questions

```
import re
import csv
p = re.compile( '(test|%|anyotherchars)') #insert bad chars insted of anyotherchars
def remove_bad(item):
    item = p.sub('', item)
    return item

raw =[] 

with open("test.csv", "rb") as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rows:
        raw.append( ( remove_bad(row[0].strip()),
                     row[1].strip().title() # are you really need strip() without args?
                    ) # here you create a touple which you will append to array
                  )

print raw
```

Comment: Okay, here's a question: Why doesn't your code remove all the bad characters?